# SQLPLUS Unable to connect in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, oracle, command-prompt, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to an oracle instance on a Linux server from my laptop using SQLPLUS at the command prompt.

I have oracle SQLDeveloper installed and i use it for interactive, but trying to get SQLPLUS running so I can set up some batch processes.

In the `COMMAND` window, I first set my `ORACLE_HOME` variable using:

`set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1`

Then I try using `SQLPLUS` to connect using:

`sqlplus -s 'myID/myPW@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DBServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)))'`

Even though I've specified a PW, it responds with Enter password: prompt and when i enter it and hit enter I receive `ERROR`

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

So, next, I set my `ORACLE_HOME` variable using: (adding `\BIN`)

`set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN`

Then I try using SQLPLUS to connect using:

```
-s 'myID/myPW@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DBServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)))'
```

THis yields 2 errors but does not prompt for password atleast:

> Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
>   SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software
>   directory

I have tried various values for `ORACLE_HOME`, but either it will prompt for `PW` and still not like it-  or it will not prompt and fail with other errors. I need it to take the `PW` value I provided and connect, but can't seem to get it to work. I also have also made sure I have read and execute permission on that directories and the `sp1us.msb` file in the `client_1\sqlplus\mesg` directory.

This is my first attempt to run SQLPLUS on my laptop. I have run it on a Linux server before and in the script there I set in the shell script file itself with:

`export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/`

and it works there.

Not sure why on my laptop I can't get it working. Open to suggestions. Thanks,

Comment: Usually on Windows environment variable `ORACLE_HOME` is not required. But put `C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows command prompt treats single quotes differently to Linux. On Linux either of these will work:

```
sqlplus -s 'myID/myPW@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DBServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)))'
sqlplus -s "myID/myPW@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DBServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)))"
sqlplus -s myID/myPW@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DBServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)))
```

unless there are any special characters hidden in your real values.

But in Windows the first of those, with single quotes, includes those quotes in the value passed to SQL*Plus. That causes it to see the whole thing as just the user name.

It then prompts you for the password; but as it also hasn't seen the connection string - since it thinks the `@...` is also part of the user name - it can't reach your DB to try to validate it, hence the ORA-12560.

So, either remove the single quotes, or switch to double quotes.

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked. I simply removed the single quotes and ran as is - and it connected and pulled data as expected.  Thanks Alex for your prompt and accurate diagnosis!